# Setting up multiple web apps on one VPS with Tomcat

Tags: configuration, tomcat6, spring-scheduled

I have a need to properly deploy multiple web applications on one VPS using Tomcat.

I was told that making use of multiple  tags is the key to doing this, but after setting up multiple  tags, I noticed an issue with my Spring scheduled jobs executing as many times as there were host tags (so if I had two host tags, my scheduled jobs would run twice).

I'm wondering if there's some way to have multiple domain names all route to their appropriate web apps with just one  tag in my server.xml file.

For example, I want to have the following domains route like so:

www.webapp1.com -> Tomcat/webapps/WebApp1
www.webapp2.net -> Tomcat/webapps/WebApp2
www.webapp3.org -> Tomcat/webapps/WebApp3

Please let me know if you need any more information, as any help you can give to me will be very much appreciated (I've been stuck for a few weeks now).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen over the past 6 months, I believe the issue was caused by the fact that I have two instances of the application running.

For example, when I navigated to `www.webapp1.com` I would be able to use the app normally, but I would also be able to access the application via `www.webapp1.com/WebApp1`

The cause of this issue is because I specified a `<HOST>` tag for `WebApp1` and I also had the app deployed in the `/webapps` folder.

The solution is that you should not put your web application in the `/webapps` folder with a `<HOST>` tag setup.  I moved the web application folder one level down and pointed the `<HOST>` tag to this folder and all was well!